# Unable to generate complete csv file from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to generate a report from a gridview which contains a complete csv listing as shown on the gridview. I'm able to generate the report however it is only generating first 10 on the list. HEres the code for my "Generate Report" button:

```
        protected void BtnGenerateReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = $"PatientList_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}.csv";

        PopulatePatientList();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={filename}");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        GvPatientList.AllowPaging = true;
        GvPatientList.DataBind();
        StringBuilder columnbind = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k = 0; k < GvPatientList.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            columnbind.Append(GvPatientList.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
        }
        columnbind.Append("\r\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < GvPatientList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < GvPatientList.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                columnbind.Append(GvPatientList.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + ',');
            }
            columnbind.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(columnbind.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Did you mean to loop over columns in the inner loop instead of rows again?

Comment: While the question looks like "typo" (due to the wrong collection used for count) please review [mre] guidance before editing the post - in this particular case it is very unclear what is the actual data you are trying to iterate over and it very well could be just 10 items. Note that "save to CSV" part should not be related to the question (I'd recommend removing that part to avoid "use proper CSV library and proper file response types" comments)

Comment: There around 40 records that appear on the gridview

Comment: Don't create your own csv. Use a specialized library like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of Code and try again

if you have paging in your gridview it will not export all the rows , it will export only the visible rows , so while exporting alone change the below line and export.

```
GvPatientList.AllowPaging = false;
```

Link : [GridView is not being exported into Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831663/gridview-is-not-being-exported-into-excel-file/73192123#73192123)

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information from the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.