# GridView is not being exported into Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I read a few posts around here but couldn't find the answer so far.

I'm using the following code to export my `GridView` into Excel file:

```
protected void btnExportClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string strFileName = "Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".csv";
    builder.Append("Firld1,Filed2,Field3,Field4,Field5" + Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvMOSS2Merchants.Rows)
    {
        string f1= row.Cells[0].Text;
        string f2= row.Cells[1].Text;
        string f3= row.Cells[2].Text;
        string f4= row.Cells[3].Text;
        string f5= row.Cells[4].Text;
        builder.Append(f1+ "," + f2+ "," + f3+ "," + f4+ "," + f5+ Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/cvs";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName);
    Response.Write(builder.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

When clicking on the button, the file is being created, but it has only headers and no data inside.

What can be wrong with that logic?

Comment: So you get a bunch of lines with nothing but 4 commas like… “,,,,” … where the data should be? If so, then are you sure `row.Cells[0].Text` is returning what you expect? What kind of app is this? winforms, WPF? ...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Those fields are empty, but I have 5 records in the  `gvMOSS2Merchants.Rows`. Looks like `row.Cells[0].text` doesn't get the data. It's just asp.net

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me
this was called in button onclick event

```
OnClick="ExportExcel"
```

**EXCEL EXPORT CODE**

```
 protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".csv");
        Response.Charset = "UTF8";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        gridviewID.AllowPaging = false;
        loadgrid();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < gridviewID.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(gridviewID.Columns[k].HeaderText.ToString() + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridviewID.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < gridviewID.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //add separator 
                sb.Append(gridviewID.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text.Replace(",", " & ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ").ToString() + ',');
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```